# iOS How can I share PDF or DOC from one app to another?

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension

I wanna share a PDF file from APP1 by the function of share extension，
but I just got a URL path from method of `loadItemForTypeIdentifier`,which is  a path of APP1 sandbox, I can not get the PDF file by URL,so how can I get the PDF or Doc through the method `loadItemForTypeIdentifier`?

[image]

I tried many types but I can only get NSURL.

Comment: Do you want to let APP2 open the app ( So every app who can open PDF ), or do you want your specific second app ?

Comment: APP2.   Forgive my poor English

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I assign item to NSData, I get a NSData.

```
[itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:fileType options:nil completionHandler:^(NSData *item, NSError * _Null_unspecified error)
                         {
                             NSData *data = (NSData *)item;
                             if ([data isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
                                 weakSelf.dataToSave = data;
                             }
                             blockExcuteCount ++;
                             if (blockExcuteCount == 2 && completion) {
                                 completion();
                             }
                        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want  share pdf to other app you don't need a share extention.you  can do it with documentViewController if to a special app you use  activityviewcontroller

Comment: My description is not very correct. I want to receive pdf from another app.